# Play Framework PersistenceException

Tags: java, oracle, playframework, persistence, ebean

I'm trying to use the Play framework (Java) to simply read some data from a few Oracle tables, probably even use a few complex queries later on. I'm following a tutorial but I'm having some issues retrieving the data.

My Model class look like this:

```java
    package models;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import play.libs.F;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import com.avaje.ebean.*;
    import play.db.ebean.*;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="TABLESPACE.CAT_BONDS")
    public class Cat_Bond extends Model {

    @Id
    public String symbol; 
    public String database; 
    public String tickType; 
    public String assetClass; 
    public String sourcePlatform; 
    public String sourceExchange;

    public static Finder<String, Cat_Bond> find = new Finder<String, Cat_Bond>(String.class,Cat_Bond.class);

    public Cat_Bond(){}

    public Cat_Bond(String symbol, String database, String tickType, String assetClass, 
                    String sourcePlatform, String sourceExchange) {

        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.database = database;
        this.tickType = tickType;
        this.assetClass = assetClass;
        this.sourcePlatform = sourcePlatform;
        this.sourceExchange = sourceExchange;

    }

    /*
     * retrieve all rows from the 'cat_bonds' table
     */  
    public static List<Cat_Bond> findAll(){
        //return new ArrayList<Cat_Bond>(cat_bond);     
        return find.all();
    }

    /*
     * Find by EAN
     */
    public static Cat_Bond findByEan(String symbol){
        return find.where().eq("symbol", symbol).findUnique();
    }   
}
```

My controller class:

```java
package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import views.html.*;
import models.Cat_Bond;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.*;

public class Cat_Bonds extends Controller {

private static final Form<Cat_Bond> cat_bondForm = Form.form(Cat_Bond.class);

public static Result list(){
    List<Cat_Bond> cat_bond = Cat_Bond.findAll();
    return ok(list.render(cat_bond));
}
```

And the application.conf entry looks like:

```
#Oracle
 db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
 db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.uk.net.intra:port/ALIAS"
 db.default.user=user
 db.default.password=pass


# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
 evolutionplugin=disabled
```

Problem is when the call to list is made in the controller then to `findAll()` in the model I get the error:

```
**[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ORA-00904: "T0"."SOURCE_EXCHANGE": invalid identifier Bind values:[] Query was: select t0.symbol c0, t0.database c1, t0.tick_type c2, t0.asset_class c3, t0.source_platform c4, t0.source_exchange c5 from TABLESPACE.CAT_BONDS t0 ]**
```

Comment: Check if the column names in that query are correct and really exist in the DB table. Can you show the table structure?

Comment: Hi Salem, the column names are the same, what I had to do for each variable defined in the model class was insert @Column(name="xxx") e.g  @Column(name="Symbol"). And that worked. But looking at the play doc and examples, this wasn't necessary.

Comment: I don't know about Oracle but some DBMS are case sensitive, so "symbol" may be different of "Symbol".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Column(name="xx")

Was required above each variable defined in the model class that was to be mapped to the table column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
clean 
compile
~run
```

If it doesn't work properly, you can use `@EntityConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.NONE)` within your model class.